# A top-like utility for monitoring CUDA activity on a GPU

Tags: cuda, process-monitoring, resource-monitor

I'm trying to monitor a process that uses CUDA and MPI, is there any way I could do this, something like the command "top" but that monitors the GPU too?

Comment: There is also nvtop https://github.com/Syllo/nvtop

Comment: "nvidia-smi pmon -i 0" can monitor all process running on nvidia GPU 0

Answer (score 174, accepted):

I find [gpustat](https://github.com/wookayin/gpustat) very useful. It can be installed with `pip install gpustat`, and prints breakdown of usage by processes or users.

[image]

Comment: after you put `watch gpustat -cp` you can see stats continuously but colors are gone. How do you fix that? @Alleo

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan use `watch -c`. @Roman Orac, Thank you, this also worked for me on redhat 8 when I was getting some error due to importing _curses in python.

Comment: `watch -c gpustat -cp --color`

Comment: `watch -n 0.5 -c gpustat -cp --color`

Comment: gpustat now has a `--watch` option: `gpustat -cp --watch`

Comment: Is there a way to output these contents to a file?

Answer (score 333):

## To get real-time insight on used resources, do:

`nvidia-smi -l 1`

This will loop and call the view at every second.

If you do not want to keep past traces of the looped call in the console history, you can also do:

`watch -n0.1 nvidia-smi`

Where 0.1 is the time interval, in seconds.

[image]

Comment: Querying the card every 0.1 seconds? Is that going to cause load on the card? Plus, using watch, your starting a new process every 0.1 seconds.

Comment: @MickT Is it a big deal? As the Nvidia-smi have this building loop!
Is the "watch" command very different from the nvidia-smi -l ?

Comment: It might be, I've seen lower-end cards have weird lock-ups and I think it's because too many users were running nvidia-smi on the cards. I think using 'nvidia-smi -l' is a better way to go as your not forking a new process every time. Also, checking the card every 0.1 second is overkill, I'd do every second when I'm trying to debug an issue, otherwise I do every 5 minutes to monitor performance. I hope that helps! :)

Comment: @Gulzar yes, it is.

Comment: You can run `nvidia-smi -lms 500` (every 500 milliseconds) over a long period of time - e.g. a week - without any issues that you might face using `watch`.

Comment: Updating every .1s, aka every 100ms, is a long time for a computer. I doubt it would make a difference in performance either way.

Comment: thank you, How can I quit it?

Comment: CTRL+C in most terminals will send the signal to close the running application, whether it is the `watch` process wrapper or the `nvidia-smi` program directly.

Comment: `nvidia-smi -l` will keep printing the table over and over again. watch nvidia-smi will display it in place.

Answer (score 91):

I'm not aware of anything that combines this information, but you can use the `nvidia-smi` tool to get the raw data, like so (thanks to @jmsu for the tip on -l):

```
$ nvidia-smi -q -g 0 -d UTILIZATION -l

==============NVSMI LOG==============

Timestamp                       : Tue Nov 22 11:50:05 2011

Driver Version                  : 275.19

Attached GPUs                   : 2

GPU 0:1:0
    Utilization
        Gpu                     : 0 %
        Memory                  : 0 %
```

Comment: I think if you add a -l to that you get it to update continuously effectively monitoring the GPU and memory utilization.

Comment: What if when I run it the GPU utilizacion just says N/A??

Comment: @natorro Looks like nVidia dropped support for some cards. Check this link http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=205165

Comment: I prefer `watch -n 0.5 nvidia-smi`, which avoids filling your terminal with output

Comment: nvidia-smi pmon -i 0

Answer (score 74):

Recently, I have written a monitoring tool called [`nvitop`](https://github.com/XuehaiPan/nvitop), the **interactive** NVIDIA-GPU process viewer.

[image: Screenshot Monitor]

It is written in pure Python and is easy to install.

Install from PyPI:

```bash
pip3 install --upgrade nvitop
```

Install the latest version from GitHub (*recommended*):

```bash
pip3 install git+https://github.com/XuehaiPan/nvitop.git#egg=nvitop
```

Run as a resource monitor:

```
nvitop -m
```

`nvitop` will show the GPU status like `nvidia-smi` but with additional fancy bars and history graphs.

For the processes, it will use `psutil` to collect process information and display the `USER`, `%CPU`, `%MEM`, `TIME` and `COMMAND` fields, which is much more detailed than `nvidia-smi`. **Besides, it is responsive for user inputs in monitor mode. You can *interrupt* or *kill* your processes on the GPUs.**

`nvitop` comes with a tree-view screen and an environment screen:

[image: Tree-view]

[image: Environment]

---

In addition, `nvitop` can be integrated into other applications. For example, integrate into PyTorch training code:

```py
import os
from nvitop.core import host, CudaDevice, HostProcess, GpuProcess
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter

device = CudaDevice(0)
this_process = GpuProcess(os.getpid(), device)
writer = SummaryWriter()
for epoch in range(n_epochs):

    # some training code here
    # ...

    this_process.update_gpu_status()
    writer.add_scalars(
        'monitoring',
        {
            'device/memory_used': float(device.memory_used()) / (1 << 20),  # convert bytes to MiBs
            'device/memory_percent': device.memory_percent(),
            'device/memory_utilization': device.memory_utilization(),
            'device/gpu_utilization': device.gpu_utilization(),

            'host/cpu_percent': host.cpu_percent(),
            'host/memory_percent': host.virtual_memory().percent,

            'process/cpu_percent': this_process.cpu_percent(),
            'process/memory_percent': this_process.memory_percent(),
            'process/used_gpu_memory': float(this_process.gpu_memory()) / (1 << 20),  # convert bytes to MiBs
            'process/gpu_sm_utilization': this_process.gpu_sm_utilization(),
            'process/gpu_memory_utilization': this_process.gpu_memory_utilization(),
        },
        global_step
    )
```

See https://github.com/XuehaiPan/nvitop for more details.

**Note**: `nvitop` is dual-licensed by the **GPLv3 License** and **Apache-2.0 License**. Please feel free to use it as a dependency for your own projects. See [Copyright Notice](https://github.com/XuehaiPan/nvitop#copyright-notice) for more details.

Comment: Nice interface, good stuff! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I received an error after install nvitop: _curses.error: curs_set() returned ERR

Comment: Note: Using `nvitop` as a dependency would require your project to be "also" GPL-licensed (if released) even if the library is simply imported. https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6033/can-a-non-gpl-python-program-use-gpl-python-module

Comment: Thanks for the notice of the licensing issue. I have updated the license of the source files.

Comment: The best thing since nvtop and gpustat!

Comment: Can we save the stats to a file for later inspection?

Answer (score 42):

Just use `watch nvidia-smi`, it will output the message by 2s interval in default.

For example, as the below image:

[image]

You can also use `watch -n 5 nvidia-smi` (-n 5 by 5s interval).

Answer (score 30):

You can try [`nvtop`](https://github.com/Syllo/nvtop), which is similar to the widely-used `htop` tool but for NVIDIA GPUs. Here is a screenshot of `nvtop` of it in action.

[image: Screenshot of nvtop in action]

Comment: very neat! thanks a lot! its also available in latest ubuntu (20.04) which was a breeze for me just doing ```sudo apt install nvtop``` and done!

Answer (score 25):

> Use argument "--query-compute-apps="

```
nvidia-smi --query-compute-apps=pid,process_name,used_memory --format=csv
```

for further help, please follow the included help

```
nvidia-smi --help-query-compute-apps
```

Comment: `nvidia-smi --help-query-compute-app`
_Invalid combination of input arguments. Please run `nvidia-smi -h` for help._

Comment: use `--help-query-compute-apps`

Answer (score 19):

Download and install latest stable CUDA driver (4.2) from [here](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-downloads). On linux, nVidia-smi 295.41 gives you just what you want. use `nvidia-smi`:

```
[root@localhost release]# nvidia-smi 
Wed Sep 26 23:16:16 2012       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 3.295.41   Driver Version: 295.41         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| Nb.  Name                     | Bus Id        Disp.  | Volatile ECC SB / DB |
| Fan   Temp   Power Usage /Cap | Memory Usage         | GPU Util. Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
| 0.  Tesla C2050               | 0000:05:00.0  On     |         0          0 |
|  30%   62 C  P0    N/A /  N/A |   3%   70MB / 2687MB |   44%     Default    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------|
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU  PID     Process name                                       Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  0.  7336     ./align                                                 61MB  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

EDIT: In latest NVIDIA drivers, this support is limited to Tesla Cards.

Answer (score 19):

Another useful monitoring approach is to use `ps` filtered on processes that consume your GPUs. I use this one a lot:

```
ps f -o user,pgrp,pid,pcpu,pmem,start,time,command -p `lsof -n -w -t /dev/nvidia*`
```

That'll show all nvidia GPU-utilizing processes and some stats about them. `lsof ...` retrieves a list of all processes using an nvidia GPU owned by the current user, and `ps -p ...` shows `ps` results for those processes. `ps f` shows nice formatting for child/parent process relationships / hierarchies, and `-o` specifies a custom formatting. That one is similar to just doing `ps u` but adds the process group ID and removes some other fields.

One advantage of this over `nvidia-smi` is that it'll show process forks as well as main processes that use the GPU.

One disadvantage, though, is it's limited to processes owned by the user that executes the command. To open it up to all processes owned by any user, I add a `sudo` before the `lsof`.

Lastly, I combine it with `watch` to get a continuous update. So, in the end, it looks like:

```
watch -n 0.1 'ps f -o user,pgrp,pid,pcpu,pmem,start,time,command -p `sudo lsof -n -w -t /dev/nvidia*`'
```

Which has output like:

```
Every 0.1s: ps f -o user,pgrp,pid,pcpu,pmem,start,time,command -p `sudo lsof -n -w -t /dev/nvi...  Mon Jun  6 14:03:20 2016
USER      PGRP   PID %CPU %MEM  STARTED     TIME COMMAND
grisait+ 27294 50934  0.0  0.1   Jun 02 00:01:40 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=gpu-process --channel=50877.0.2015482623
grisait+ 27294 50941  0.0  0.0   Jun 02 00:00:00  \_ /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=gpu-broker
grisait+ 53596 53596 36.6  1.1 13:47:06 00:05:57 python -u process_examples.py
grisait+ 53596 33428  6.9  0.5 14:02:09 00:00:04  \_ python -u process_examples.py
grisait+ 53596 33773  7.5  0.5 14:02:19 00:00:04  \_ python -u process_examples.py
grisait+ 53596 34174  5.0  0.5 14:02:30 00:00:02  \_ python -u process_examples.py
grisait+ 28205 28205  905  1.5 13:30:39 04:56:09 python -u train.py
grisait+ 28205 28387  5.8  0.4 13:30:49 00:01:53  \_ python -u train.py
grisait+ 28205 28388  5.3  0.4 13:30:49 00:01:45  \_ python -u train.py
grisait+ 28205 28389  4.5  0.4 13:30:49 00:01:29  \_ python -u train.py
grisait+ 28205 28390  4.5  0.4 13:30:49 00:01:28  \_ python -u train.py
grisait+ 28205 28391  4.8  0.4 13:30:49 00:01:34  \_ python -u train.py
```

Comment: You can also get the PIDs of compute programs that occupy the GPU of all users without `sudo` like this: `nvidia-smi --query-compute-apps=pid --format=csv,noheader`

Comment: Sometimes `nvidia-smi` does not list all processes, so you end up with your memory used by processes not listed there. This is the main way I can track and kill those processes.

Comment: @grisaitis Carefull, I don't think the `pmem` given by `ps` takes into account the total memory of the GPU but that of the CPU because `ps` is not "Nvidia GPU" aware

Comment: Not quite "filtered on processes that consume your GPUs.". They can just change settings... But I don't know a better alternative...

Comment: right now you monitor CPU performance of any processes that operate (actually compute, change settings or even monitor) GPUs. I guess this is NOT what was asked in original question. I think question was just about "compute" part...

Answer (score 7):

This may not be elegant, but you can try

```
while true; do sleep 2; nvidia-smi; done
```

I also tried the method by @Edric, which works, but I prefer the original layout of `nvidia-smi`.

Comment: Or you can just do `nvidia-smi -l 2`. Or to prevent repeated console output, `watch -n 2 'nvidia-smi'`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the  monitoring program [glances](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances) with its  [GPU monitoring](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances/issues/170) plug-in:

- open source
- to install: `sudo apt-get install -y python-pip; sudo pip install glances[gpu]`
- to launch: `sudo glances`

[image]

It also monitors the CPU, disk IO, disk space, network, and a few other things:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In Linux Mint, and most likely Ubuntu, you can try "nvidia-smi --loop=1"

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to find the process which is running on gpu, you can simply using the following command:

```
lsof /dev/nvidia*
```

For me  `nvidia-smi` and `watch -n 1 nvidia-smi` are enough in most cases. Sometimes `nvidia-smi` shows no process but the gpu memory is used up so i need to use the above command to find the processes.

Answer (score 2):

I created a batch file with the following code in a windows machine to monitor every second. It works for me.

```
:loop
cls
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI\nvidia-smi"
timeout /T 1
goto loop
```

nvidia-smi exe is usually located in "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation" if you want to run the command only once.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `nvidia-smi pmon -i 0` to monitor every process in GPU 0.
including compute mode, sm usage, memory usage, encoder usage, decoder usage.

Comment: what is the difference between pmon and dmon?

Answer (score 0):

There is [Prometheus GPU Metrics Exporter (PGME)](https://github.com/chhibber/pgme) that leverages the nvidai-smi binary. You may try this out. Once you have the exporter running, you can access it via http://localhost:9101/metrics. For two GPUs, the sample result looks like this:

```
temperature_gpu{gpu="TITAN X (Pascal)[0]"} 41
utilization_gpu{gpu="TITAN X (Pascal)[0]"} 0
utilization_memory{gpu="TITAN X (Pascal)[0]"} 0
memory_total{gpu="TITAN X (Pascal)[0]"} 12189
memory_free{gpu="TITAN X (Pascal)[0]"} 12189
memory_used{gpu="TITAN X (Pascal)[0]"} 0
temperature_gpu{gpu="TITAN X (Pascal)[1]"} 78
utilization_gpu{gpu="TITAN X (Pascal)[1]"} 95
utilization_memory{gpu="TITAN X (Pascal)[1]"} 59
memory_total{gpu="TITAN X (Pascal)[1]"} 12189
memory_free{gpu="TITAN X (Pascal)[1]"} 1738
memory_used{gpu="TITAN X (Pascal)[1]"} 10451
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `nvidia-smi` in *device monitoring* mode, e.g.:

```
$ nvidia-smi dmon -d 3 -s pcvumt
# gpu   pwr gtemp mtemp  mclk  pclk pviol tviol    sm   mem   enc   dec    fb  bar1 rxpci txpci
# Idx     W     C     C   MHz   MHz     %  bool     %     %     %     %    MB    MB  MB/s  MB/s
    0   273    54     -  9501  2025     0     0   100    11     0     0 18943    75  5906   659
    0   280    54     -  9501  2025     0     0   100    11     0     0 18943    75  7404   650
    0   277    54     -  9501  2025     0     0   100    11     0     0 18943    75  7386   719
    0   279    55     -  9501  2025     0     0    99    11     0     0 18945    75  6592   692
    0   281    55     -  9501  2025     0     0    99    11     0     0 18945    75  7760   641
    0   279    55     -  9501  2025     0     0    99    11     0     0 18945    75  7775   668
    0   279    55     -  9501  2025     0     0   100    11     0     0 18947    75  7589   690
    0   281    55     -  9501  2025     0     0    99    12     0     0 18947    75  7514   657
    0   279    55     -  9501  2025     0     0   100    11     0     0 18947    75  6472   558
    0   280    54     -  9501  2025     0     0   100    11     0     0 18947    75  7066   683
```

Full details are in `man nvidia-smi`.