# How can I use the watch command with a customized nvidia-smi output message?

Tags: linux, command, nvidia, watch

I use the `nvidia-smi` command quite frequently, and I have a separate alias in my .bashrc that I use to monitor it (`alias gpu='watch -n 3 nvidia-smi'`).

I recently learned about customizing the output message of `nvidia-smi` and am using the following: `nvidia-smi | tee /dev/stderr | awk '/ C / {print $3}' | xargs -r ps -up` that I got from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50264491/how-to-customize-nvidia-smi-s-output-to-show-pid-username).

I'd like to replace the original `nvidia-smi` command in my `watch` alias, but am wondering how I can do so. Simply replacing it doesn't work, and I've tried surrounding the new command in quotation marks but that leads to the original `nvidia-smi` message along with a

```
error: user name does not exist

Usage:
 ps [options]

 Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
  or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).
```

right below it.

How should I go about achieving what I want? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is running `nvidia-smi | tee /dev/stderr | awk '/ C / {print $3}' | xargs -r ps -up` without watch successful ?

Comment: Yes, that prints out the message I want. It prints out the original output of `nvidia-smi` and has rows below that with columns being usernames, commands run, etc.

Comment: What is your new alias ?

Comment: Right now it loos like this: `"watch -n 3 \"nvidia-smi | tee /dev/stderr | awk '/ C / {print $3}' | xargs -r ps -up\""`. I've tried removing the quotations around the `nvidia-smi` full command, but that also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to see if it produces expected result :

```
alias gpu='watch -n 1 "nvidia-smi | tee /dev/stderr | awk '"'"'/ C / {print \$3}'"'"' | xargs -r ps -up"'
```

`'"'"'` is to escape single quote inside single quotes.

Comment: Is there any way to pipe the output of this into a `tail` command if I wanted to see only the bottom portion of the output?

Comment: Try to remove `tee /dev/stderr |`

Comment: Removing that portion leads to an `error: user name does not exist` message without the output of `nvidia-smi`. Right now I tried running the alias `alias gpu='watch -n 1 "nvidia-smi | awk '"'"'/ C / {print \$3}'"'"' | xargs -r ps -up | tail -n $(($LINES - 2))"'`

Comment: You need to put  `\$((LINES - 2))`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. :( I'll figure it out.