# Check if GPU is shared

Tags: cuda

When the GPU is shared with other processes (e.g. Xorg or other CUDA procs), a CUDA process better should not consume all remaining memory but dynamically grow its usage instead.

(There are various errors you might get indirectly from this, like `Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR`. But this question is not about that.)

(In TensorFlow, you would use `allow_growth=True` in the GPU options to accomplish this. But this question is not about that.)

Is there a simple way to check if the GPU is currently used by other processes? (I'm not asking whether it is configured to be used for exclusive access.)

I could parse the output `nvidia-smi` and look for other processes. But that seems somewhat hacky and maybe not so reliable, and not simple enough.

(My software is using TensorFlow, so if TensorFlow provides such a function, nice. But if not, I don't care if this would be a C API or Python function. I would prefer to avoid other external dependencies though, except those I'm anyway using, like CUDA itself, or TensorFlow. I'm not afraid to use `ctypes`. So consider this question language invariant.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `nvmlDeviceGetComputeRunningProcesses` and `nvmlDeviceGetGraphicsRunningProcesses`. ([Documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/nvml-api/group__nvmlDeviceQueries.html).)
This is a C API, but I could use `pynvml` if I don't care about the extra dependency.
[Example usage](https://github.com/wookayin/gpustat/blob/b52fe9a8ad874a826e0dea4baa3436ec5762a832/gpustat/core.py#L451) ([via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223811/a-top-like-utility-for-monitoring-cuda-activity-on-a-gpu)).

Comment: You can also check (at least via CUDA runtime API) the amount of memory of the GPU and how much of that is currently being used by all prrocesses